# Swift Parse kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I want to use `query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;`
in my `PFQueryTableViewController`, but it tells me it dos not exisit.

I have imported `Parse` in my class and `ParseUI` trough the BridgingHeader

Here my BridgingHeader

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "ParseUI.h"
#import "RSKImageCropViewController.h"
```

What am i doing wrong? All libarys are imported trough Cocoapods.

Comment: The cache policy stuff is pretty old I think, I recommend you go with Local Datastore if you want to have offline functionality. And the default for a query is network only anyways, so I don't think you have to specify.

Comment: When there is no internett connection, parse keeps trying to load. How do i handle stuff like that?

Answer (score 1):

The enumeration types for PFQuery.cachePolicy changed with Swift.

Try typing in:  PFCachePolicy. 
then you will see the enumerations available for this type.

For example, your statement would be as follows:
   query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.NetworkOnly
or you can use the Swift abbreviated notation:
   query.cachePolicy = .NetworkOnly